# Can I explode a transformed object in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, smartobject, blending-objects

I created a circle in illustrator.

To create an array, I added `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform`.

The problem is, now I want the array of circles to be individual objects.

Is it possible to explode them somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

`Object > Expand Appearance` (if available)

And

`Object > Expand`

--or--

`Object > Flatten Transparency` and move the slider all the way to the right.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was clicking around for ages last night trying to find that!